# sas: In a text string how to find a word after a trigger

Tags: search, cpu-word, sas

I am using SAS to do some word searching. I have a character string

```
var1 = "blah blah...Trigger random_word blah blah";
```

I would like to search for `trigger`, which is 5 characters wide and select the `random_word` after that. `Random_word` can be 0 to 13 character wide.

How can I do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var2 = scan(substr(var1,index(var1,"trigger")),2);
```